# defer.reject() in protractor does not show the stack trace? That is, I don't know which line of the code

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor, angular-promise, deferred

I use defer.rejct() as error handling method.
However, when it throw failure, it did not show the stack trace.
Is there a easy way for exception catch in protractor using promise?

```
function formatPoolRecordsGridData(row) {
var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
switch (record.poolLevelRecordType) {
    case "A":
       <do something here>
       break;
    default:
        //Error Handling
        defer.reject('There is no matched record type');
        break;
}
//There is no way to say which line of the code it is failed
        Message:
        Failed: There is no matched record type
      Stack:
        Error: Failed: There is no matched record type
            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:101:16
            at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
            at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
```

Comment: reject with error object which will only catch the stack trace.ex: reject(new Error("There is no matched record type"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error object will only catch the stack trace which will be useful for debugging

Reject will only reject the promise and call the corresponding fail method

reject with error object which will only catch the stack trace.ex:

```
reject(new Error("There is no matched record type"));
```